# how to draw multiple draggable and selectable circle?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+

i wrote somecode to draw circles on a panel by mouse click, i need to add some feature like selecting and dragging this circles , help me to complete my code please, thanks

[Screenshot of running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URJVq.png)

CircleItem class:

```
public class CircleItem
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public Color CircleColor { get; set; }
        public Point StartPoint { get; set; }
        public int LineWidth { get; set; }
        public String Caption { get; set; }

        public CircleItem(String caption, Color circleColor,Point startPoint,int lineWidth)
        {
            CircleColor = circleColor;
            StartPoint = startPoint;
            LineWidth = lineWidth;
            Caption = caption;
        }
        public void Draw(Graphics G)
        {
            using (var pen = new Pen(Color.DimGray, LineWidth))
            {
                G.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(CircleColor), StartPoint.X, StartPoint.Y, 25, 25);
                G.DrawEllipse(pen, StartPoint.X, StartPoint.Y, 26, 26);
                G.DrawString(Caption, new Font("Arial", 9), Brushes.Green, StartPoint.X + 6, StartPoint.Y + 6);
            }
        }
        public bool HitTest(Point Pt)
        {

            return true;
        }
```

Main code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int circleNumber;
        private Point positionCursor;
        private List<Components.CircleItem> circleItems = new List<CircleItem>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            typeof(Panel).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.SetProperty
            | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
            picCanvas, new object[] { true });
            picCanvas.Paint += PicCanvas_PaintEventHandler;
        }
        private void PicCanvas_PaintEventHandler(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            foreach (CircleItem cItem in circleItems) cItem.Draw(e.Graphics);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void picCanvas_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void picCanvas_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            positionCursor = this.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 25, Cursor.Position.Y - 25));
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                circleItems.Add(new CircleItem(circleItems.Count.ToString(), Color.White, positionCursor, 4));
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (CircleItem cirTag in circleItems)
                    cirTag.CircleColor = cirTag.HitTest(e.Location) ? Color.Red : Color.White;
            }
            picCanvas.Invalidate();
        }

        private void picCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```

Thanks for attention :)

I try to wrote some code to done this, i don't have any good result, circle collision routin needed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465188/wpf-how-to-draw-a-circle-and-drag-it-around

Comment: @Ren: This seems to be about Winforms. Make sure the Panel is doublebuffered. In the mousemove if a button is down trigger drawing.. In the MouseDown do the hittest over your list and keep a hit. Clear previous hits, optionally depending on the keystate. All drawing should hapen by invalidating the Panel. In the Paint event make a difference for the/any selected items. - Note: Since you items are just geometry, ie not controls you need to do the hittest yourself by testing the mouseposition to be inside the circle..!

Comment: @Renat my panel doublebuffer is enable, how can i calculate hit area when mouse down for circle, thanks

Comment: @Renat thanks bro, that's wpf but i need done in winforms

Comment: see [low level (no frameworks) example of a drag & drop, re-order-able list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924609/2521214) for some inspiration ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve selecting circles problem by GraphicPath(),just working on drag and drop circles now

```
public class CircleItem
{
    private bool Selected { get; set; }
    public Color FillColor { get; set; }
    private int LineWidth { get; set; }
    private String Caption { get; set; }
    private Point Center { get; set; }
    private int Radious { get; set; }

    private GraphicsPath path;
    public CircleItem(String caption, Color fillColor,Point startPoint,int lineWidth,int radious)
    {
        FillColor = fillColor;
        LineWidth = lineWidth;
        Caption = caption;
        Center = new Point(startPoint.X-radious,startPoint.Y - radious);
        Radious = radious;
    }
    public void Draw(Graphics G)
    {
        path = new GraphicsPath();
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.DimGray, LineWidth))
        {
            G.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(FillColor), Center.X, Center.Y, Radious-1, Radious-1);
            G.DrawEllipse(pen, Center.X, Center.Y, Radious,Radious);
            G.DrawString(Caption, new Font("Arial", 9), Brushes.Green, Center.X + 6, Center.Y + 6);
            path.AddEllipse(Center.X, Center.Y, Radious, Radious);
        }
    }
    public bool HitTest(Point Pt)
    {
        bool result = false;
        result = (bool)path.IsVisible(Pt);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @StefanG hi i draw a path around my circles, just send current mouse position to HitTest and check is cursor inside in path or not ,it's great method to detect mouse cursor inside your target or not

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do

#### Fix your hittest

This should be fairly simple, just compute the distance to the center point of the circle, and either check if this is lower than the radius, or the same as the radius (with some tolerance factor).

#### Keep track if you are moving the circle

This require a basic state machine. You need to keep track of some 'state' i.e. what circle is selected (if any), if the mouse button is pressed, and an offset from the mouse position to the circle center.

When you MouseDown on a circle you should set all of this state. You then need an event handler for the MouseMove event where you check if the button is pressed, and if so, update the position of the circle center to the mouse position + the offset. You also need a listener for the MouseUp-event to reset the state when the button is released.

You could use `Mouse.LeftButton` property instead of maintaining a flag for `mouseDown` yourself, but you would still need to keep track what circle was clicked, if any.

Comment: thanks for your tips,i'm working on ...